# How to do a web.config transform during build for local debugging?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, web-config

I have a web application (.NET 4.8 Framework) and I need to be able to test on local machine with various settings and I do not want them accidentally checked into source code repository.

For example, `web.config` would have our standard settings, but my `web.local.config` would have settings I may need to debug a client's problem. It would be marked as "ignored" for the purposes of git commits.

I installed the SlowCheetah extension and nuget but that does not seem to work. When testing, the transform is not being performed. The value in the `web.config` is shown on the page. The transformonbuild is not showing in the project file.

I am even open to adding a post build script.

- Visual Studio 2019 Community
- .NET Framework 4.8

Comment: SlowCheetah allows you to automatically transform app.config (or any file) when you press F5 in Visual Studio. You can perform different transformations depending on your build configuration. If you cannot convert normally, it is recommended to conduct a case test according to the requirements of [Official Document](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscps.SlowCheetah-XMLTransforms). If it still doesn't work you need to reinstall SlowCheetah to make sure it works properly